# java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Tags: tomcat

I have installed two version of Tomcat 7 and 8 on same system. For some reason. i needed to remove Tomcat 7 from system . When im tryting to revert Tomcat 7, im unable to do so , not even i m able to remove service . In Service manager it is showing as Stopping. 
As this is still in process since last 3 days , port is being used. Hecne i m not able to start Tomcat 8 as well. As same port is referred here too. I tried changing port from 8080 to 8089 / 8009 but  i m facing below error

31-May-2017 14:18:56.021 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
31-May-2017 14:18:56.037 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Answer (score 0):

Where are you changing port?
You have to do so in CONF dir.
Change server.xml and change every referred port not only startup, because if you don't do so the server will not run correctly

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you tried to change port on Tomcat 8. Try

```
ps -aux
```

on Linux or netstat on Windows to make sure that new port is free.

Can't you just kill the Tomcat 7 process from the command line?
(kill -9 on Linux or on Windows: https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/kill-processes-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7)